# window.getSelection does not work with japanese (EUC-JP) websites

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I am getting a problem with greasemonkey script (jquery) where I cannot get text from  japanese (EUC-JP) websites, instead getting weird symbols.

Here is  [Script](https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/93166) and website http://www.geocities.jp/npp_euc_jp/
 to test.
I tried to search on google but no answers

Comment: I think you should perhaps ask this question on the [greasemonkey script discussion page](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/discuss/93166). Your question doesn't give very much information.

Comment: The script does work on unicode websites but not on non unicode, if you install and test it on the geocities website you will see that it does not get the japanese text but some weird characters.Its a mirror website, I cannot post a comment on it.

Comment: Well, `window.getSelection().toString()` works for me with Japanese text in Chrome: https://i.imgur.com/ASvXK32.png

Comment: @MattFletcher what's wrong with asking here? Agree the issue needs a [mcve] but why direct user to another site?

Comment: @charlietfl My thinking was because it's relating to a bug in someone else's project, which normally you'd file an issue with the original developer. Because even if we find a solution to it, the OP will be creating a fork of the project, and the original code will still be broken

Comment: The issue isn't with `window.getSelection()` anyway! The browser will just automatically escape the characters when it finds it in a URL. Here you can see where I've set the href attr to contain JP text. It still fills in the correct characters in the dom. However Chrome converts it once you try and go to that link: https://i.imgur.com/wzHEEc7.png

Comment: is not window.getSelection(); i try select content in that site , all OK

Comment: Where is position of text form in that site?

Comment: I've written an answer now, the magic function is `encodeURI()`

Comment: Forget to state I use firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with `window.getSelection()`. The issue is with URL encoding. However, this can be fixed by running the string through [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).

So, in [this code](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/93166), you'd want to replace this line:

```
var seltext = getSelectedText();
```

... with this:

```
var seltext = encodeURI(getSelectedText());
```

This will then make sure the values getting piped into the `attr()` are properly encoded before sent to Google.